# Does the browser save css rules locally when testing?

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, opera

So when editing my website I noticed that sometimes the CSS would not update when I would look at it in the browser. For instance, I would change the font size from 5 to 15 on my hosting company but it would still display as 5 in the browser, but when I changed browsers OR added "www." to the front of the URL it would show up as 15. This has been happening for a while and I can't seem to find a fix. It seems to happen when I view the CSS in the browser debug window. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, chrome is caching your files. You can disable it (at least when the dev tools are open) by going to the network tab and then checking **"Disable cache"**

Comment: To refresh a page and clearing its' cache, you could always press `Shift + F5` in a Chrome browser.